# Turbine Server does not discover Hystrix Streams in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, spring-cloud, fabric8

We have several spring-boot (1.5.13.RELEASE) services running in OpenShift. We are exposing REST APIs annotated with @HystrixCommand.
These services are exposing hystrix stream on /actuator/hystrix.stream endpoint.

I use turbine-server with hystrix dashboard in order to consume the stream. So when I provide a valid URL (i.e. http://spring-boot-service-name.namespace.svc/actuator/hystrix.stream where spring-boot-service-name.namespace.svc is valid OpenShift domain name with active endpoints) I can see an appropriate metrics in a hystrix dashboard.

Now I want to consume turbine stream, that should be exposed on my turbine-server. To aggregate hystrix streams I use the following dependencies:

- `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-turbine` and `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard` from `Edgware.SR3` release train
- `io.fabric8.kubeflix:turbine-discovery:1.0.28`
- `io.fabric8.kubeflix:ribbon-discovery:1.0.28`

I've followed kubeflix guide and examples provided here https://github.com/fabric8io/kubeflix. 
So, I've provided the following env variable in my turbine-server container:

```
env:
  - name: TURBINE_INSTANCEURLSUFFIX
    value: ":8080/actuator/hystrix.stream"
```

I've added the following properties: `turbine.aggregator.clusters.default=my-namespace.*`
and `clusterNameExpression` for turbine-server:

```
turbine:
  appConfig:
  clusterNameExpression: new String("default")
```

All OpenShift configuration files for spring-boot services (DeploymentConfig,Service) contains `hystrix.enabled="true"` and `hystrix.cluster="default"` labels.

However, when I try to get the turbine stream (by providing http://turbine-server/turbine.stream) there is nothing to show up on the dashboard (except "Loading...") and sometimes, I get the following exception in my turbine-server logs:

```
2018-08-21 10:43:30.424 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.n.t.s.TurbineStreamingConnection       : Got exception when writing to response stream

org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:321) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceHttpServletResponse.flushBuffer(TraceHttpServletResponse.java:50) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:159) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.turbine.streaming.servlet.SynchronizedHttpServletResponse.flushBuffer(SynchronizedHttpServletResponse.java:79) ~[turbine-core-1.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.netflix.turbine.streaming.servlet.TurbineStreamServlet$ServletStreamHandler.noData(TurbineStreamServlet.java:226) ~[turbine-core-1.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.netflix.turbine.streaming.TurbineStreamingConnection.waitOnConnection(TurbineStreamingConnection.java:214) ~[turbine-core-1.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.netflix.turbine.streaming.servlet.TurbineStreamServlet.streamFromCluster(TurbineStreamServlet.java:136) [turbine-core-1.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.netflix.turbine.streaming.servlet.TurbineStreamServlet.doGet(TurbineStreamServlet.java:98) [turbine-core-1.0.0.jar!/:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework
.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) [spring-security-oauth2-2.0.15.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:166) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1276) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:607) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:597) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:646) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.flush(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:169) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:252) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1564) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:317) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
... 99 common frames omitted
```

How can I deal with this and is it possible to do such thing in OpenShift environment?

I want to notice that I am totally aware that such combination of dependencies might not work, but as far as I know there is no turbine-discovery provided by spring-cloud-kubernetes yet. So, currently, I am trying to figure out how can I get things working.

Comment: In OpenShift, unlike plain Kube, access to the REST API is locked down. Are you running the application needing to do discovery under a service account which has REST API access enabled? http://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-do-i-enable-rest-api-access-for-an-application.html

Comment: Previously I've got spring exception saying there is no permissions for default serviceaccont.I've provided the following command in openshift cli  `oc policy add-role-to-user view system:serviceaccount:my-namespace:default`  Since than I haven't issues anymore.